# How can we check input entry is empty or not which is converted into float while getting the input from the user?

Tags: python

Getting input from the user and convert it into the float, while getting the entry from the user and then I want to check if user press enter without giving any input or value then it will bring the user to again enter the marks.

```
while(True):
    assign1=float(input("Please enter the marks: "))
    if(assign1>100 or assign1<0):
        continue
    else:
        marks=(assign1*20)/100
        break
```

Comment: Perhaps you should have a `try/except` around your `float(...)` line, to deal with any non-numeric input the user might enter.

Comment: Thank you so much i got my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'd go with a `try/except` clause:

```
while(True):
    try:
        assign1=float(input("Please enter the marks: "))
    except:
        continue
    if(assign1>100 or assign1<0):
        continue
    else:
        marks=(assign1*20)/100
        break
```

In this way, anything that raise an error when converted to float (including '', or *Enter without giving any input*) will result in he repetition of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`try/except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) to handle the exception. Please find below code. Hope it helps.

```
while(True):
    try:
        assign1=float(input("Please enter the marks: "))
    except Exception as e:
        print (e) ## do you stuff with error
    else:       
        if(assign1>100 or assign1<0):
            continue
        else:
            marks=(assign1*20)/100
            break
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I thought you want the user to ask again if input was invalid. That is why I did not add continue. :)

Comment: The `continue` in the `except` block has zero effect on the code in this case.

Comment: This solution is more pythonic than mine